# Html.DisplayNameFor() using dynamically calculated properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, system.reflection

I have a class object with more than 30 properties

```
public class Person
{
    [Display(Name = "A")]
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "B")]
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "C")]
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
    ... 
    ...
    [Display(Name = "Z")]
    public string PropertyZ { get; set; }
}
```

In my view file, I am iterating through the properties dynamically:

```
@model Person

<div>
   @foreach(var prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
      // logic to decide if the property should be
       // included in the output or not
      <div>@prop.Name</div>
   }
</div>
```

This will list all of the properties, with each property in its own `div`.
What I need to do is output the `Display` of each property.
Something like javascript way of addressing an object's properties by `[]`. I.E:

```
      <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[prop.Name])</div>     //does not work
```

This is what I tried:

```
   @foreach(var prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
   {

      <div>@Html.DisplayNameFor(prop.Name)</div>             //does not work

   }
```

My goal is to later filter out properties that are not required in the view, without having to manually edit the view when I decide to alter the class (by adding or removing properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LINQ to identify an object that contains the `Display` attribute and select the `Name` argument value:

```
@foreach (var prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    // TODO: logic to decide if the property should be included in the output or not

    foreach (var ca in prop.CustomAttributes)
    {               
        var name = ca.NamedArguments.Where(t => t.MemberName.Equals("Name")).Select(x => x.TypedValue.Value).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
        <div>@Html.DisplayName(name)</div>
    }
}
```